# Password protect a printer in the network?

Tags: wireless-networking, printer, network-printer

I have a wireless printer that connects to my wifi router. There is a function in the printer that allow me to lock the printer temporarily so no one can print/scan... and unlock it. The problem is the wifi network is being shared with other people and I don't want them to access printer and print out everything. 
My question is how can I prevent others from accessing printer. I can print with mobile phone and computer so is there a way to do so. I can not modify the network as well.
Printer model (in case): Brother DCP-L2540DW

Comment: Subnet your network.  Connect the printer to the subnet with only devices you want to print, separate from devices, that cannot.  Basic networking 101 solution

Comment: Doing so requires two routers

Comment: Some Brother printers support "secure function lock", which does what you want. To see if yours does, go to its web page, click Administrator Settings and then Secure Function Lock. See http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/htmldoc/mfc/cv_dcp8085dn/gb/html/uk/nug/chapter11_4.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that ability is built into the printer (which it looks like it is) then follow the manual from the Brother website:

> Start your web browser.
>
> Type "http://machine's IP address" in your browser's address bar
>   (where "machine's IP address" is the machine's IP address). For
>   example: http://192.168.1.2
>
> Click the Administrator tab.
>
> Click the User Restriction Function menu in the left navigation bar.
>
> Select Secure Function Lock.
>
> Click Submit.
>
> Click the Restricted Functions menu in the left navigation bar.
>
> In the User List / Restricted Functions field, type a group name or
>   user name (alphanumeric, up to 15 digits).
>
> In the Print and the other columns, select a check box to allow or
>   clear a check box to restrict the function listed.
>
> To configure the maximum page count, select the On check box in the
>   Page
>
> Limits column, and then type the maximum number in the Max. Pages
>   field.
>
> Click Submit.
>
> Click the User List menu in the left navigation bar.
>
> In the User List field, type the user name.
>
> In the PIN Number field, type a four-digit password.
>
> Select User List / Restricted Functions from the drop-down list for
>   each user.
>
> Click Submit.

[Secure Lock Function](http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/htmldoc/mfc/cv_dcpl2520dw/use/manual/index.html#GUID-3DA45B8B-2090-4120-8980-851F216BE464_455)

Comment: I didn't find the Secure Function Lock because the printer states above does not support but I did find restrict by IP address. Thanks.